# Cloning a database to another collation

Tags: sql-server, migration, collation

I'm not sure if this is the best way to migrate data to another collation but I've done the following:

1. Scripted the source database and changed the collation in the script
   to my required one
2. Ran the script and created the new database with the wanted
   collation (along with all the tables,triggers,indexes etc.
3. I tried to 'Export Data' from the SQL Server management studio but I
   got an error related to code page differences.
4. Since Export/Import Data didn't work, I resorted to using bcp to
   mass export all the tables in the source database to txt files.
   After that I began importing the rows using bcp but I saw some
   errors related to truncation and invalid characters.

What's the best/proper way to migrate the data from a database with a different code page & collation after creating the clone from the scripted source?

Comment: What collations would the source and destination be? You are likely to need explicit data conversion rules.

Comment: @vonPryz The source collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (code page 1251) and the destination collation is Arabic_CI_AS (code page 1256).
How do I go about converting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. In SSIS, in the SSIS ToolBox there is a component called Transfer
   Database task.
2. use the method provided [here](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/seven-step-process-changing-database-collation)
3. use the method provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302405/The-Easy-way-of-changing-Collation-of-all-Database)

I would probable go with 3), but that is a matter of taste.

Comment: I want to go with 3) but the scripts used there mention compatibility with only SQL Server 2005 + 2008. Would it apply to 2012/2014 as well?

Comment: @AuthenticReplica; yes
I forgot to mention this link, which I wrote in 2008. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic442391-146-1.aspx

Comment: @AuthenticReplica; 
And to warn you that you may have characters that you cannot convert from one collation to another. I think SQL Server will complain about this, hence the error you got.

Comment: @AuthenticReplica; there is also a new post on sqlservercentral.com; http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Collation/99305/